# Laravel ignores the method in the controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

There controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return View::make('hello');
    }
}
```

and in the presence of the router:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

an error:

```
BadMethodCallException 
Method [index] does not exist.
```

The command `php artisan routes`, returns what you need:

```
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI        | Name | Action               | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD / |      | HomeController@index |                |               |
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Version: `Laravel 4.2.11`

[Russian version of the question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375598/php-laravel-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Comment: Try using `getIndex` instead of `index`.

Comment: @Jerodev, I tried to rename the methods of this problem persists :)

Comment: strange. everything looks ok.... how are you calling it?

Comment: @itachi, just turn on the url.

Comment: @itachi http://test.app/ is present in the root .htaccess

    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
     RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons this would be happening.

1. There is another controller somewhere called HomeController.
2. Your controller is namespaced.

If it's the first, remove the other version and if it's the second, add the namespace to the 'uses' parameter in the router definition.

Comment: Thank you, I was not paying attention. In your `vendor/laravel `directory was `laravel` which was the root directory with a copy of the root